# Can I use CollapsingToolbarLayout in a Fragment from Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, fragment, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

Can I use CollapsingToolbarLayout in a Fragment from Navigation Drawer.
I try [this sample](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) from AndroidHive.
I want "Messages" to Collapsable to NestedScrollView.In a Activity is OK,but it is in a Fragment. CollapsingToolbarLayout cannot hover to Original Toolbar.But which I want to try may be the wrong pattern.Please advise me how it would be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm removing the actual activities toolbar on the Fragment's `onResume` and re-enabling the activities toolbar on the Fragment's `onStop`.

Please, add this code on your fragment:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    ...
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.app_bar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().findViewById(R.id.app_bar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: @HtooAungHlaing add setHasOptionsMenu(true);  to your onCreateView()

Comment: This wont work with navigationView in Activity and coordinatorlayout in fragment