# Fragment with CollapsingToolbar showing Activity Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a CollapsingToolbarLayout in my fragment and is showing fine, the thing is that App Toolbar is also being showed. I try this solution: [Can I use CollapsingToolbarLayout in a Fragment from Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474401/can-i-use-collapsingtoolbarlayout-in-a-fragment-from-navigation-drawer) but is not working for me...

This is my fragment AppBarLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:contentScrim="#FFf3802b"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/brandLogo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/logo_icon"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar_krono"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/fragment_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    ...

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My parent activity (activity_main.xml):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/appToolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- NavigationView to display slider menu -->
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I'm using in myFragmentActivity (just to try) this line to change the title of my APPToolBar and it really change:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

Then, i try to hide my appToolbar by using this line but is not working, my appToolbar is always being showed:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Which type of layout are you using in the activity where you are inflating this fragment? Maybe a CoordinatorLayout can solve your problem.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Comment: i updated my XML, as you can see in my fragment layout, i use CoordinatorLayout

Comment: And how about the parent Activity?

Comment: my activity_main.xml is just a normal activity with a NavigationView (new NavigationDrawer) and a FrameLayout to display my fragments, my Toolbar and my DrawerLayout... (i updated my code, you can see it now)

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment replaces the inner layer, but not Acitvity toolbar. That all worked properly should be placed together with fragment container and toolbar. In your code:

```
<!-- Use this LinearLayout for container -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/correct_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/appToolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Sure we can use another solution. We can create function in MainActivity and call in all fragments for closing actual Toolbar (Perform other code different from yours).  And other....

Comment: "Your fragment replaces the inner layer, but not Acitvity toolbar" I know that... that's why i'm getting the instance of my Activity Toolbar from de Fragment by calling ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar(), but the thing is if i can change de title, why i can't hide it?

Comment: I am thinking in create my Toolbar in every fragment and not in my MainActivity but i don't know if is a good practice... I think it will work but i think there is a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Change the color to transparent when you switch the your collapsing layout fragment.

Go through this you will get your solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57771274/5328951