# Hiding SupportActionBar in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-toolbar

I want to hide my MainActiviy Toolbar in my fragment, i'm using:

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.appToolbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

and:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

and is not working. My fragment has his own Toolbar, and is already been showed, but my Activity Toolbar is being showed too. What am i doing wrong? I just want to show my fragment ToolBar

Comment: you should use the activity which loads the Fragment, (which has actionBar), for example if you are loading fragment in HomeActivity. try ((HomeActivity) getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();

Comment: is not working... same issue :-( . I try this code in other fragment and it works, the difference between one fragment and other is that when i replace it, i'm adding one into backstack and the other is not being added... (the toolbar disappear when the fragment is not added to th backstack)

Comment: It would be great if you can upload some code snippet, it will help to analyze the issue.

Comment: Actually you can see the full issue in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658981/fragment-with-collapsingtoolbar-showing-activity-toolbar/33660875

Comment: Show your code and xml?

Comment: Actually the issue was that i am adding the fragment to the backstack, and we cannot delete or hide the SupportActionBar if we have "something" in the backstack, i delete the addToBackStack() method in my project and i am already deleting my supportBar from my Fragment

Answer (score 0):

The ActionBar is owned by the Activity not by the Fragment, so you need to call .hide() method on this Activity, try in this way:

```
getActivity.getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide(); cannot be resolved... i have to  use ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();

Answer (score 0):

If you use [`AppCompat toolbar`](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html). Solution:

1. Must hide `Actionbar` before using `AppCompat Toolbar` by apply suitable `NoActionBar` theme following: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme)
2. Setup `AppCompat toolbar` to activity using this [guide](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html):

r

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appToolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);//replace ActionBar with toolbar
findViewById(R.id.appToolbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);//hide if you want
```

Comment: in my main activity i'm setting my toolbar like this 
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);ç

Comment: You must replace `Actionbar` before using AppCompat Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue was that i am adding the fragment to the backstack, and we cannot delete or hide the SupportActionBar if we have "something" in the backstack, i delete the addToBackStack() method in my project and i am already deleting my supportBar from my Fragment