# android - collapsing toolbar and fragment layout not working together

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my app I have two fragments and a MainActivity. The activity_main.xml contains a collapsing toolbar which works perfectly for me when the fragments are empty. In my first fragment I fetch json data from a server and put it into a listview inside the fragment activity. The data is fetched and shown correctly, but the listview takes the whole screen and my collapsing toolbar seems to be a little buggy, like sometimes it pops up and disappears and my listview is not scrollable anymore. The two activities aren’t working together at all. Is there a way to make them work together?
My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="center|bottom"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="56dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backg"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/backthree"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" >

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My fragment_first.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorGrayHell"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:dividerHeight="10dp"
                android:divider="@color/colorGrayHell"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned where the fragments are attached - I assume within the NestedScrollView? If not, that's where they should go.

The problem is most likely the ListView within the fragment - unlike a RecyclerView, it does not implement NestedScrollingChild2 and ScrollingView, which are required for the collapsing toolbar functionality.

Replace the ListView with a RecyclerView and make sure the fragments are within the NestedScrollView that has `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` and it should work.

Comment: I only add them programmatically, not in the xml files, is both necessary? I haven’t got the code in front of me, but I will look at it as soon as possible. I think they are added to the frameLayout. The hint with the recyclerView is a good point, I‘m gonna try it!

Comment: @Mike Adding them programmatically is perfectly fine, as long as they are added somewhere below the NestedScrollView that has `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"`. This is so that when the RecyclerView within the fragment is scrolled, it delegates the scrolls to the NestedScrollView, which has the AppBar behavior that allows it to expand and collapse the AppBar.

Comment: So I would add the all fragments I have below the NestedScrollView in the main.xml, or do I get that wrong?

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguous wording, what I actually meant is the fragments need to be placed somewhere WITHIN the NestedScrollView (not below it).

Comment: @Ovidiu I have done the same mentioned by you. The problem I am facing is slowness/jerks while scrolling recyclerView when one of its child is another recycler view. Any idea how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fcfcfc"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Yogesh" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/bg1"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:title="Test"

                />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Use this code.
And also you need to change color of tollbar which swutching fragment.

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), android.R.color.transparent));
                    mFragmentToSet = new HomeDashboardFragment();
```